# How to find the all parent node of a child node from bottom to top in tree view control using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, treeview

Here i have below Treeview as shown in image.

[image: treeview]

for child node `G g` i want to fetch all the parent nodes name from bottom to top and store into list. means in list should  add G g, F f, D d, B b.

please suggest the solution.

thanks in advance...

Comment: When your building your treeview add them to a list, much easier than fetching them afterwards... Otherwise your going to have to loop through looking for the parents which I think is redundant when you can do it building the treeview.

Comment: tree is already there with data. i have one child node name only. so for that child node i need to fetch the parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created one function for it which will add all the parent in the list until parent is not nothing for the selected node.

```
Public Function AllParents() As List(of String)
    Dim listOfNodeHierarchy As New List(Of String)
    listOfNodeHierarchy.Add(node.ToString)
    'If Child Node has parent, add the parent name of the Child node to the list
    While (node.Parent IsNot Nothing)
        listOfNodeHierarchy.Add(node.Parent)
        node = node.Parent
    End While
    return listOfNodeHierarchy
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to obtain information about the parents node.

```
dim selectedNode as treeNode = YourTreeViewSelectedNode   

dim nodePath as string= ""   'will store the full path 

'You get the full Path of the node like  'Parent\Child\GrandChild
'The Procedure will fill nodePath  

ObtainNodePath(selectedNode,nodePath)

msgbox(nodePath)



Private Sub ObtainNodePath(ByVal node As TreeNode, ByRef path As String)

    If node.Parent IsNot Nothing Then

        path = IO.Path.Combine(node.Text, path)    ' Parent\Child 

        If node.Parent.Level = 0 Then Exit Sub

        'Call again the method to check if can extract more info
        ObtainNodePath(node.Parent, path)

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the list of text of the parent nodes, you can simply use the FullPath property of the selected node:

```vb
For Each s As String In _
  TreeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.Split(TreeView1.PathSeparator).Reverse
```

If you need the list of nodes, just keep checking the parent until it's nothing:

```vb
Private Function ParentNodes(fromNode As TreeNode) As IEnumerable(Of TreeNode)
  Dim result As New List(Of TreeNode)
  While fromNode IsNot Nothing
    result.Add(fromNode)
    fromNode = fromNode.Parent
  End While
  Return result
End Function
```